# Jenkins+AWSLoadBalancerController example

Tags: jenkins, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I'm building a jenkins cluster in Amazon EKS and am trying to register Jenkins with the AWS Load Balancer Controller. I could use a bit of advice from some more experienced folks.

Here is my values for Jenkins helm3 install (I'm still a bit new at helm):

```
clusterZone: "cluster.local"
renderHelmLabels: true

controller:
  componentName: "jenkins-controller"
  image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  tag: "2.263.3"
  imagePullPolicy: "Always"
  adminUser: "admin"
  adminPassword: "admin"
  jenkinsHome: "/var/jenkins_home"
  jenkinsWar: "/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war"
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "50m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "2000m"
      memory: "4096Mi"
  usePodSecurityContext: true
  runAsUser: 1000
  fsGroup: 1000
  servicePort: 8080
  targetPort: 8080
  serviceType: NodePort
  serviceAnnotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "jenkins-ingress"

  healthProbes: true
  probes:
    startupProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
      failureThreshold: 12
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 5
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: '{{ default "" .Values.controller.jenkinsUriPrefix }}/login'
        port: http
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 5
  agentListenerPort: 50000
  agentListenerHostPort:
  disabledAgentProtocols:
    - JNLP-connect
    - JNLP2-connect
  csrf:
    defaultCrumbIssuer:
      enabled: true
      proxyCompatability: true
  agentListenerServiceType: "ClusterIP"

  installPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.29.0
    - workflow-aggregator:2.6
    - git:4.5.2
    - configuration-as-code:1.47

  JCasC:
    defaultConfig: true

    securityRealm: |-
      local:
        allowsSignup: false
        enableCaptcha: false
        users:
        - id: "${chart-admin-username}"
          name: "Jenkins Admin"
          password: "${chart-admin-password}"
    authorizationStrategy: |-
      loggedInUsersCanDoAnything:
        allowAnonymousRead: false

  sidecars:
    configAutoReload:
      enabled: true
      image: kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:0.1.275
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      reqRetryConnect: 10
      sshTcpPort: 1044
      folder: "/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs"

  ingress:
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: >-
            {{ template "jenkins.fullname" . }}
          servicePort: 8080
    # path: "/jenkins"
    apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
    annotations:
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "jenkins-ingress"
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"

persistence:
  enabled: true
  existingClaim: jenkins-0-claim

rbac:
  create: true
  readSecrets: false

serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name: "jenkins"
```

Here is the contents of my ingress.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: jenkins-ingress
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}, {"HTTP":
      8080}, {"HTTPS": 8443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app1-nginx-nodeport-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app1/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: app2-nginx-nodeport-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app2/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: app3-nginx-nodeport-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app3/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /jenkins/*
```

Here is the error, I suspect it is due to the namespace.  Jenkins is in it's own namespace:

```
❯ kubectl describe ingress app-ingress
Name:             app-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          internal-k8s-jenkinsingress-9f4e69d9f1-2066345703.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /app1/*      app1-nginx-nodeport-service:80 (10.216.66.254:80)
              /app2/*      app2-nginx-nodeport-service:80 (10.216.66.248:80)
              /app3/*      app3-nginx-nodeport-service:80 (10.216.66.174:80)
              /jenkins/*   jenkins:8080 (<error: endpoints "jenkins" not found>)
Annotations:  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: jenkins-ingress
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: [{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}, {"HTTP": 8080}, {"HTTPS": 8443}]
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
              alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                 From     Message
  ----     ------             ----                ----     -------
  Warning  FailedDeployModel  35m (x16 over 37m)  ingress  Failed deploy model due to InvalidParameter: 1 validation error(s) found.
- minimum field value of 1, CreateTargetGroupInput.Port.
  Warning  FailedBuildModel  7m2s (x15 over 34m)  ingress  Failed build model due to ingress: default/app-ingress: Service "jenkins" not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue.  Turns out I was defining the the jenkins path in too many places.  I removed it from the primary ingress definition and altered my jenkins helm values.

I also set service type to NodePort instead of ClusterIP

Removed this from app-ingress.yaml:

```
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /jenkins/*
```

Removed path value from jenkins helm ingress definition and set the jenkinsUriPrefix to "/jenkins".